# A working example of dojo's registry.findWidgets()

Tags: javascript, dojo

Can someone give me a working example of registry.findWidgets() in dojo 1.7+?

Whatever I do, I get an empty array. For example:

```
var myTextBox = new TextBox({
    name: "firstname",
    value: "",
    placeHolder: "type in your name"
}).placeAt("root"); 
myTextBox.startup();  

console.log(registry.findWidgets('root'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FYYqx/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `findWidgets()` incorrectly. According to the API, it accepts up to two arguments:

1. `root` - The `DOMNode` to search under, and
2. `skipNode` - A node to not search under (optional).

You're calling it with a string, which will return an empty list. Instead, pass in the `DOMNode` of whatever node you want to use to locate widgets. If you wanted to use `myTextBox`, for example, this is what you would do:

```
console.log(registry.findWidgets(dom.byId("root")));
```

Note that this will only return the first level of widgets - it does not descend recursively into the widget structure. If you want to descend the widget tree, you must implement this on your own.

Comment: What @Zemljoradnik probably wants is `console.log(registry.findWidgets(dom.byId("root")));`

Comment: Well, I'm an idiot. I was sure I tried it, but it turns out I made some mistake in the process. Thanks. And I think this is one of the flaws of dojo, that it's inconsistent. In most of the places throughout the toolkit, when method accepts a DOM node, it accepts a string (node id) as well. But obviously not always.

Comment: Errors are a language's way of saying, "check the API." ;)